# Number of unique cycle paths on an octahedron

Tags: combinatorics, platonic-solids

I am looking at the number of unique cyclic paths along the edges of an octahedron. A cycle starts and ends on the same vertex and an edge can only be walked once. They are also considered equivalent under rotation, but not reflection.

For example the two smallest (length=3) paths are the clockwise and anti-clockwise paths around a single triangular face.

There are then three (length=4) paths. One is the square around the middle and then there are the clockwise and anti-clockwise paths that surround two adjacent faces.

I found a clockwise and anti-clockwise (length=5) and then six different variations of (length=6) paths.

This makes a total of 13 unique cyclic paths. Is this the correct number, or have I missed anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also consider the Eulerian path in the example on this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianCycle.html

Comment: The Eulerian path reuses vertexes, its a path strategy thats more about using each edge once. My paths cannot reuse edges or vertexes. They represent the "ant-walking" degrees of freedom before returning to a know state (staring vertex). These paths represent the alphabet of a "natural" turing machine based on octahedral geometry.

Comment: Why do you differentiate between the clockwise and counter-clockwise cycle of length three? Are the cycles directed? So that they can only be transversed in one direction?

Comment: Yes they are directed, CW and ACW are not identical and cannot both be created by rotation from a single arbitrary length 3 path. Why do I make this distinction? I guess you're either rotation invariant or not. I'm looking at the octahedron more as a dimensionless graph that indicates the notion of degrees of freedom on the graph. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We are going to count the cycles that go through the bottom vertex.

we first count the cycles that pass through the bottom vertex but not the top vertex.

We separate into clockwise and counter-clockwise movement along the square. We do clockwise case, there are $4$ ways to get from the bottom vertex to the square, then we must pick how soon we go back down, it can be after $1,2$ or $3$ edges of the square have been travelled, then the answer is $4\times 3=12$, however notice this is only half because we must also count clock-wise. Thus there are $24$ cycles that do not reach the top.

We now count how many paths do reach the top. To do this we separate into three type of cycles.

The first type is when you go up immediately after reaching the square, there are $4$ ways to get to the square, then you go to the top, once at the top you must go down, here things get slightly tricky, there are three consecutive spots on the square to which you can descend, however now matter where you go down, there are going to be three ways to finish the cycle from there. Thus there are $4\times3\times3=36$ cycles of this kind.

The second type is when you go up after moving $1$ edge on the square, there are $4$ ways to get to the square, from here there are $2$ directions to move. Once you move $1$ edge on that direction you go up. After going up you must go down, there are $2$ choices and no matter which one you pick there will be $2$ ways to finish the cycle from there. Thus there are $4\times 2 \times 2 \times 2=32$ cycles of this type.

the third type is when you move $2$ edges once you get to the square, notice there are $4$ ways to get on the square and then $2$ directions to move those $2$ edges on the square, after this you must go up, and from here there is only one way to finish, thus there are $4\times 2=8$ cycles of this type.

Thus there are $24+36+32+8=100$ cycles, however be careful, because we counted each cycle twice, because we counted oriented cycles, so the final answer is $50$ cycles that pass through the bottom vertex.

Using the first result there are $12$ cycles that pass through the top vertex but not the bottom.

Finally there is one cycle that does not pass through the top or bottom vertex.

So adding up there are $63$ cycles.

Comment: I think you have counted too many paths. The solutions need to be invariant under rotation. That is "the system behaves the same regardless of how it is oriented in space". By this I mean that for example there are only the clockwise and anticlockwise three sided path as all other three sided paths can be obtained via rotation. I like the combinatorial approach, can it be refined?

Comment: Oh, I should have read, I will delete this question tomorrow and add a new one also tomorrow, I think that you are missing some cycles though, for example the cycle of length four that passes through the top and bottom vertices and opposite vertices in the square, unfortunately I don't have time to do it today, but I will count it carefully tomorrow and come back. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: There are three squares, one for each orientation, but they are all obtained by rotation after picking any one. Also by rotation there is no left or right handed path for the square, so I count it as one.